# Как проверить строку на наличие недопустимых символов?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Проверить введенную пользователем строку на наличие недопустимых символов.
В качестве первого символа допустимы только буквы и знак подчеркивания.
Остальные символы могут быть буквами, цифрами и знаком подчеркивания.

```
s = input('Введите строку: ')

print('Исходная строка: ', s)

t = list(('qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюёЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮЁ_'))

if s[0] in set(t):
    print('Первый символ - нет недопустимых символов.')


else:
    print('Недопустимый(-e) символ(-ы).')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Python` для проверки того, есть ли значение или элемент в последовательности используется оператор `in`, в случае же если необходимо хотя бы одно совпадение из целой структуры данных можно воспользоваться оператором `any`, тогда если обобщить, то имеем такой алгоритм:

```
inp_string = input('Введите строку: ')

print('Исходная строка: ', inp_string)

blacklist = list('АБВГД')

print(any(i in blacklist for i in inp_string))
```

---

**Тесты**

```
Исходная строка:  ЕЕВЕЕ
True

Исходная строка:  ЕЕЕТ
False
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.